# How to set UI change for log out icon

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am using wpf to build a new application. I have a log out button and an icon for that. i have a expander where log out button is placed. If log out is clicked, icon should change to circular progress bar. now i'm hard coding the circular progress bar. I want it to be dynamic when expander is collapsed or expanded.

Comment: Welcome. We do not have the insight and program as you do. therefor you need to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you can get any help!

Comment: Please consider reading our [ask] topics. Currently, your question is too broad because it's missing a [mcve] of your current setup.